# Ошибка при общении через сокет ПК - вирутальная машина

Tags: python

server

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 9090))
sock.listen(10)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print(addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    if 'text' in data.decode('utf-8'):
        conn.send('good'.encode('utf-8'))

conn.close()
```

client

```
import socket

def client():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
    key = 'text'
    sock.send(key.encode('utf-8'))
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if 'good' in data.decode('utf-8'):
        print('nice')
    sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```

Написал сокет клиент сервер но когда отправляю файл client на вирутальную машину на одном ПК мне выдаёт ошибку
`ConnectionRefusedError: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение`
Я не очень понимаю в чем проблема и прошу совета

Comment: Очевидно, у ПК и у виртуальной машины два отдельных никак не связанных друг с другом локалхоста, вот они друг друга и не видят

Comment: Я пробовал изменять в клиенте на 127.0.0.1 не помогло

Comment: Потому что 127.0.0.1 это тот же самый локалхост. Нужно ковыраться в настройках виртуальной машины и прокидывать общую с ПК сеть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настрой сеть через мост, тогда будет все нормально. Ванную что сетка сейчас настроена через NAT

Comment: Да решил проблему тем что установил сетевой мост и в client на ВМ выставил ИП ПК